# Condições diferentes da mesma coluna

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho uma tabela chamada `anuncios`:

```
id | nome   | finalizar | datafim
1  | teste1 | N         | 0000-00-00
2  | teste2 | S         | 2018-12-05
```

Gostaria de fazer um `SELECT` listando apenas os registros onde o valor da coluna `finalizar` seja `N` ou que seja `S`, desde que quando seja `S`, a `datafim` seja menor ou igual a hoje.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a seguinte instrução:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM anuncios
 WHERE (finalizar = 'N' OR (finalizar = 'S' AND datafim <= GETDATE()))
```

Comment: Olá. Não deu certo. Retornou o seguinte erro: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch() on boolean

Comment: Você está executando no sql server ou mysql? Realizei o teste no SQL Server e funciona. Pode informar os tipos de cada campo ou em específico no campo "finalizar"?

Comment: Deu certo aqui. obg